# Can I use Linear Regression or do I need Nonlinear Regression

Tags: r, regression, nonlinear-regression, transform

I am trying to fit these two equations to data in R via regression.

First Equation:

$$y(x) = a + \frac{b}{c + x^m}.$$

This equation is constant plus reciprocal function, resulting in a hyperbolic response that approaches the asymptote $a$ with time approaching infinity.

Can this equation be transformed i.e. by taking logs of both sides, so as to enable it to be fitted to a data set by linear regression? Or does it need nonlinear regression?

Second Equation:

$$y(x) = a + \frac{b}{c + x^m} + \frac{(a + b/c)^{1/2}}{d}\cdot x + \frac{1}{4d^2}\cdot x^2.$$

The constant and reciprocal function are the same, with the addition of a linear and quadratic component added. Can this be also be performed by linear regression, or do I need nonlinear regression?

Comment: I would attempt to fit the equation using the `nls()` function.

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e. Yes I have done that manually for one set of data, but I need to automate it and automating Start Values (Self Starters) is turning into a bit work which I haven't solved yet, so was hoping that I might be able to to transform it and do with linear regression so no need for the start values.

Comment: Your second equation looks incorrect, it is the original equation plus two additional terms.  Sorry, but since the equation is non-linear, linear regression isn't an option here. If automating the start values is a problem.  Try creating a new question, outlining the problems you are having.

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e yes I've since released the two additional terms of the second equation is incorrect. Thanks for looking into this for me. Now that I have fixed the two additional terms (not correct here) I will attempt to define some data driven rules for parameter ranges so I can use nls2 to find the most appropriate starting values. I then use nlsML to solve the regression.